# Postgresql - support more languages (Hebrew)

Tags: django, database, postgresql, internationalization, hebrew

I am using django + postgres server-side.

I searched a lot about this, but didn't find anything - **How can I support more languages in postgres?**

If I send a POST request to the django app with text in **Hebrew**, it stores it in the database as `??????`.

How can I get Postgres to store my data correctly?

Comment: Support for Hebrew in Postgres  is explained in the documentation about character set support:  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html.

Comment: thanks. I looked at this page already, but didn't figure out how can I add Hebrew support in an existing database? not creating a new one. is there a command I should do? or change the settings somewhere? thanks!

Comment: What text encoding is the database set to use? `SELECT current_setting('server_encoding');` . You'll want to be using UTF-8. If you aren't, you'll need to dump the database, drop it, re-create it with utf-8 encoding and restore the dump.

Comment: The encoding is utf-8. the problem ended up being in my android app, I was not encdoing the request and response in euf-8. thanks anyway :)